# Disk space (3TB) used up while running LAMMPS

Tags: debian, disk-usage

Every time, I run [LAMMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMMPS) for 4-5 days, the disk space (3TB) would be used up. I tried to find possible temporary files using commands like:

1.`du -d 5`

2.`du -h --max-depth=1`

3.`du . | sort -nr | head -n50`

However, I cannot find these files. `du` command shows that the diskspace is used by some files in my working directory. There don't seem to be any files that are over large.  If I reboot the server, the space is released.  How can I find these temporary files and delete them safely?  Or any other solution will be highly appreciated.

Output of `df -h` after running *LAMMPS* around 24 hours:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   3.5T  1.2T 2.2T  35%  /
udev                     10M   0    10M   0%   /dev 
tmpfs                    6.4G  2.0M 6.3G  1%   /run 
/dev/mapper/cosmos-root  3.5T  1.2T 2.2T  35%  / 
tmpfs                    5.0M  0    5.0M  0%   /run/lock 
tmpfs                    13G   315M 13G   3%   /run/shm 
/dev/sda2                229M  18M  199M  9%   /boot
```

**Please do not arbitrarily mark my question as duplicated one!**

Comment: This Q should specify where the working directory is mounted.  Please also include the output of `df -h`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Below is the output. after running LAMMPS around 24hrs.  Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   3.5T  1.2T  2.2T  35% / 
udev                      10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    6.4G  2.0M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/cosmos-root  3.5T  1.2T  2.2T  35% /
tmpfs                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     13G  315M   13G   3% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                229M   18M  199M   9% /boot

Comment: What makes you think the files are in your working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Since everything seems to be mounted on one big root partition, the `du` commands clearly aren't being aimed where they should be.  Maybe you're running `du` in some subdirectory of `/home`, but *LAMMPS* is filling up log files in `/var` or `/var/log`.

Run this in a background terminal during the fillup, it'll show the ten largest files opened by any processes named "*lammps**" or "*lmp**", and also highlight any changes as those largest files grow:

```
watch -d "lsof -c lammps -c lmp | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8,9 | sort -urn | head"
```

Note: the above code assumes that disk space is consumed by a few large and growing files.  It's possible the disk space might also be consumed by millions of small files.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48523/discussion-on-answer-by-agc-disk-space-3tb-used-up-while-running-lammps).